# Finding Duplicate Dates by a certain ID in a single table

Tags: sql

Here is what my data looks like

```
ID          Date             Other Field
123        1/2/2017        a
123        1/3/2017        b
123        1/3/2017        c
123        1/5/2017        d
123        1/6/2017        e
123        1/6/2017        f
456        2/4/2017        g
456        2/4/2017        h
456        2/5/2017        i
456        2/6/2017        j
```

I am looking to identify when there is a date that is duplicated by ID, i would like to return the entire record. The results would look like

```
ID        Date          Other Field
123      1/3/2017      b
123      1/3/2017      c
123      1/6/2017      e
123      1/6/2017      f
456      2/4/2017      g
456      2/4/2017      h
```

I am not sure how to identify duplicate dates within a single table, then return those records only individually.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
t1.* from
table t1
join
(select id,date,count(*) from
table t2
group by id,date
having count(*)>=2
) t2
on t1.id=t2.id and t1.date=t2.date
```

Comment: Should there be a HAVING statement in the subquery noting 2 or more?

Comment: @baineschile:yes,i missed it,added now

Comment: Thanks for your help! Figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using? If it supports window functions (e.g. Oracle or PostgreSQL), then:

```
select
  id, "date", other_field
from
(
  select
    tbl.*,
    count(*) over (partition by id, "date") date_cnt
  from tbl
)
where date_cnt >= 2
```

Comment: ssms 16, but i figured out the solution. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @baineschile Can you post the solution?

Comment: I used the top solution. It needed a HAVING clause to work.